# response.writefile("filename.png") works when fired via button, but not when fired via callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, callback

I have an application in which I want to force an image to download, and not be displayed in the browser.  response.writefile seems to accomplish this.

However, if I call my method programatically from within my ICallBackEvent Handler nothing happens.  No error is thrown, it just sort of hangs.

Steping through the codes shows that the method runs, but the file doesn't download and the CallBack never finishes.  I have no idea what is going on.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    downloadtest();
}

public string downloadtest()
{
    string fileName = "";

    string outPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/") + @"logo.png";

    fileName = "logo.png";

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
    Response.WriteFile("logo.png");
    Response.End();

    return fileName;
}
```

So, it works great if i click the button.

But if I call downloadtest() from my callback code, nothing happens.

Thank you for any ideas.

Here is my callback code.

It's lengthy, but here are big chunks of it.

Server Side First...

```
                String cbReference = Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "arg", "ReceiveServerData", "context");
                String callbackScript = "function CallServer(arg, context)" + "{ " + cbReference + ";}";
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallServer", callbackScript, true);

.......

 #region ICallbackEventHandler Members

        string CBResult = string.Empty;

        public string GetCallbackResult()
        {
            return CBResult;
        }

        public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
        {
            string[] args = eventArgument.Split(',');
            string sessionidvar = args[0];
            string Argument = args[1];

            GeoCollection<Overlay> MapOverlays;

            string statepath = OverlayClass.SetStatePath(sessionidvar);

            CBResult = string.Empty;

            switch (Argument)
.......

case "contribution":

                    downloadtest();
                    CBResult = "contribution";

                    break;
```

Client Side....

```
function mapHeatLayerLoad(HEATLAYER) {

    var sessionid = $('.logo').attr('data-SessionId');
    var offset = $('#divMap').offset();

    var HTML = "<div id='mapupdatingdiv'><H1>Map Updating...</H1>";
    HTML += "<img id='mapLoaderGif' src='/images/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Image'/>";
    HTML += "</div>";

    $('#divMap').append(HTML);

    CallServer(sessionid + "," + HEATLAYER, "");
}

..........

function ReceiveServerData(rValue) {
    var argArray = rValue.split(',');
    var map = Map1.GetOpenLayersMap();
    var sessionid = $('.logo').attr('data-SessionId');

    var PenetrationLayer = map.getLayer("PenetrationOverlay");
    var ContributionLayer = map.getLayer("ContributionOverlay");
    var PenChangeLayer = map.getLayer("PenChangeOverlay");
    var ConChangeLayer = map.getLayer("ConChangeOverlay");
    var CompetitorLayer = map.getLayer("CompetitorOverlay");
    var HighLightLayer = map.getLayer("HighLightDynamicOverlay");
    var ZipBordersLayer = map.getLayer("ZipBordersOverlay");
    var PSALayer = map.getLayer("PSAOverlay");
    var SSALayer = map.getLayer("SSAOverlay");
    var WaterLayer = map.getLayer("WaterOverlay");
    var HighwaysLayer = map.getLayer("HighwaysOverlay");
    var ASCIconLayer = map.getLayer("ASCIconOverlay");
    var HospitalIconLayer = map.getLayer("HospitalIconOverlay");
    var ASCLayer = map.getLayer("ASCOverlay");
    var HospitalsLayer = map.getLayer("HospitalsOverlay");
    var ClientLayer = map.getLayer("ClientOverlay");

    $('#mapupdatingdiv').fadeOut('slow', function () { $('#mapupdatingdiv').remove(); });

    switch (argArray[0]) {

........


        case "contribution":

            map.getLayer("ContributionOverlay").redraw(true);
            BuildLegend(2);
            break;


......
```

Comment: When you call your method via callback, is it actually go to inside the downloadtest() ?

Comment: The call back goes to a section of code on the server,  from here downloadtest() is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I can't initiate a Response.xx from a call back.  I set up a hidden asp button that performs the function I want and then call that from JavaScript with a post back.